# Choosing a random natural number with bijection with rationals

Tags: probability-theory, random

It's said that you can't choose a random natural number. But what if you take a bijection between the natural numbers and, say, the rational numbers in the unit interval, and then choose a random rational number from that interval, and then take the corresponding natural? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: And how do you "choose a random rational in the unit interval"? What is the probability distribution that makes each rational equally likely, and has probability 1 of picking *some* rational? That's really the issue with "choose a random natural number". If you want to make each natural number equally likely, then the probability that you pick any one natural number needs to be $0$, but then the probability of picking *some* natural number is also $0$. You have the exact same problem trying to come up with a uniform probability distribution for the rationals in the unit interval.

Comment: You can choose a random natural number, you just can't assign all of them the same probability. The same is true of the rationals, for the same reason.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But you can choose a random real number, even though the probability of picking any one real number is 0.

Comment: Yes, but there are uncountably many real numbers, which prevents Arturo's argument from working in that case. (Technically: probabilities are _countably_ additive, but not uncountably additive).

Comment: @user12186: As Henning points out, the problem is that probability needs to be *countably additive* (if you have countably many independent events, then the probability that at least one of them occurs is the sum of the probabilities of each one of them). For the natural numbers/rationals, that means that if each of them has probability $0$ of being chosen, then the probability that *any one* is chosen is $0$ (because you can obtain the total probability by adding all the individual probabilities). You can't do that for real numbers. If you drop uniformity, then there's no problem for $\bf N$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30619/probability-of-picking-a-specific-value-from-a-countably-infinite-set. I'm unsure whether this should be closed as a duplicate of that -- the original question goes in a different direction, but the OP's comment seems to show that the underlying issue is the same.

Comment: Perhaps a better duplicate is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14167/probability-of-picking-a-random-natural-number).

Comment: Thanks, countable additivity settles it. Now I'd like to know how you could modify that requirement so that choosing a random rational number would be possible, since it seems like a totally sensible thing to want to do. But that should probably be a another question.

Comment: The Poisson distribution, the geometric distribution, the binomial distribution, etc. all choose a random natural number.  The practice of using the word "random" to mean "uniformly distributed" seems to be a persistent meme among all mathematicians _except_ probabilists and statisticians.  Or maybe "all" is exaggerated, but "many" isn't.

Comment: It's completely sensible to choose a random rational number. You just can't have every rational numbers be equally likely. But you can get all rational numbers in $[0,1]$ _with the same (fully reduced) denominator_ to have the same probability. That probability would need to be lower for larger denominators, though.

Comment: "...so that choosing a random rational number would be possible, since it seems like a totally sensible thing to want to do." Unfortunately, many things that it is totally sensible to want to do aren't actually possible to do. Choosing a random rational number uniformly at random is one such thing; finding an algorithm that determines if a Diophantine equation has a solution in integers is another.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Maybe it should be "almost all". Then us algebraists can interpret it as "all except perhaps for a finite number".

Answer (score 2):

The question was thoroughly answered in comments:

> You can choose a random natural number, you just can't assign all of them the same probability. The same is true of the rationals, for the same reason. *-- André Nicolas*

and

> the problem is that probability needs to be countably additive (if you have countably many independent events, then the probability that at least one of them occurs is the sum of the probabilities of each one of them). For the natural numbers/rationals, that means that if each of them has probability $0$ of being chosen, then the probability that any one is chosen is $0$ (because you can obtain the total probability by adding all the individual probabilities).  *-- Arturo Magidin*

I'll answer the follow-up question

> Now I'd like to know how you could modify that requirement [countable additivity] so that choosing a random rational number would be possible

-- the natural weakening of countable additivity is finite additivity. It is possible to put a finitely additive measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb Z$ so that the measure is shift-invariant and $\mu(\mathbb Z)=1$. See [invariant mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group). Every finite set gets measure zero. The set of even numbers gets measure $1/2$, formalizing the statement  "half of all integers are even". So far so good. But there is no canonical (or even explicit) invariant mean $\mu$; their very existence relies on the axiom of choice. So, it's not clear what concrete *and* nontrivial probability statements one can get out of the existence of $\mu$.