# Two natural numbers are selected at random, what is the probability that the sum is divisible by 11?

Tags: probability

This same question to check divisibility by 10 is quite straightforward but when we have to check whether it is divisible by 11 there is one case that has to be excluded, I would like it if someone explains it intuitively.

edit: Nvm its not very different from 10 or any other number n

Comment: Please, explain what is your problem in more details. There are usually several different proofs for a single result, and not everyboby know every possible proof

Comment: There is no notion of selecting natural numbers in a (uniformly) random fashion, as is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14167/81360)

Comment: In what way is the problem easier for division by 10?

Comment: If you replace $10$ by any other $n$, the result is $\frac{1}{n}$. So, $10$ is nothing special. Another thing is if you want a divisibility-rule.

Comment: wait yeah, i understand now, my bad its nothing special i was thinking a little too much, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have fixed one number, the other can have $11$ possible residues mod $11$, one of which is suitable. Hence the answer is simply $\frac{1}{11}$

Comment: This can be even more illustrative if you draw a table with 11 rows and cells where rows stand for a mod 11 and columns - for b mod 11 (where a and b are your numbers), and each cell is a sum of its row and column number. You will see one cell with 0, 9 cells with 11 and 1 cell with 22 (out of 121), giving you 11/121 = 1/11, as @Peter said

Comment: Thank you @Andrei Rykhalski , that was what i was searching for, Peter that also makes sense, Thank you!